# How do I replace() input chars in a input string?

Tags: python, string, loops, replace, char

The purpose of my program is to ask a user to input a sentence , then the user is asked to input any amount of characters they would like removed from the string.
the program only replaces the last character to be input , not all of them

please keep in mind I'm fairly new at this :)

```
print("Please enter a sentence")



sentence = input()



print("Please type the  characters you would like to make dissapear!!! ")


while True:
    repchar = input()

    for i in repchar:
    
        i = sentence.replace(repchar , "")

    if repchar == "":
        print(i)
        break
```

Answer (score 1):

It was a minor error. You needed to make changes to the whole sentence, but since `i` changes in every iteration, the replaced sentence was never stored.

```
print("Please enter a sentence")
sentence = input()
print("Please type the  characters you would like to make dissapear!!! ")
while True:
    repchar = input()

    for i in repchar:
    
        sentence = sentence.replace(repchar , "") # here you were replacing the 
                                                  # character but storing it in i 
                                                  # that changes every iteration

    if repchar == "":
        print(sentence) # Printing the sentence not just i
        break
```